# .NET Framework and compatibility

Tags: c#, .net

We have a case where 2 .NET applications are running on the same computer, A is built for 4.6.1 and B is built for 4.5. This means that we have to install .NET framework 4.6.1 for A but this breaks a certain part(printing) of application B. Application B will have to be fixed but in the meantime, how do we solve this? I have read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility

It states that I should set the supportedRuntime like this:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

But will this really solve my problem? Is 4.6.1 containing 4.5 as a whole as well?

Comment: Have you checked IIS ? If you have 2 applications pools, one running in 4.6.1, the other in 4.5, i should see no issue.

Comment: Try to set `sku` attribute like this: `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />`

Comment: @Mekap No such thing. Application Pools can be set to run against a RunTime, for which there is `1.0`, `2.0` and `4.0`. `4.6.1` and `4.5` refers to Frameworks, for which you can only install one (they are your base libraries).

Comment: @Dennis, the question is if this will run v4.5 as if it was the only installed version or if v.4.6.1 will still be used but with a setting? The later would probably still result in problems(like raceproblems or something like that).

Comment: What is the printing issue? All other description is useless.

Comment: @Aron thanks, i did not now that. I always thought this was impacting runtimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run 4.5 on a machine with 4.6.1 installed. It doesn't make sense the question. The 4.6.1 version of the .net framework will be loaded, since those are the only libraries you have installed. 4.6.1 is meant to have a library that has every function of the 4.5 library, but in practice 4.5 was a buggy piece of crap, and a lot of bugs were removed. Of course one man's bug is another man's feature....

So in short if you are using the 4.5 framework API, you have no problems.

However if you are relying on a 4.5 bug, you are stuffed.

More to the point, 4.5 is no longer supported.

Update: .net Core v1.0 has gone live.

The framework for .net Core is deployed by nuget, so you can use multiple versions for that. You could install `.net 4.5` and `.net Core 1.0` concurrently, and it might solve your problem.

Comment: And its not possible to install and run multiple versione of .NET Framework at the same time?

Comment: @Banshee Yes. It is, but each one must be a different RunTime. The exception to this rule is .net core. Which was designed around nuget because of how stupid this is.

Comment: Just bite bullet, migrate 4.5 app to 4.6. The problems should be minimal. In future keep code bases in sync. If you need it now, binding redirects work well but should not be long term.